# Como armazenar </br> e \n no banco de dados, e mostrar em HTML em seguida, quando for chamado?

Tags: php, html, postgresql, yii, yii2

Estou armazenando no atributo *ofe_desc* a descrição de uma oferta, mas mesmo que na TextArea eu insira quebra de linhas, no banco e no HTML (Quando eu tento recolher os dados), são todos mostrados em um linha unica.

Segue códigos:

```
 <!-- Mostra na tela os dados da tabela -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-border-color panel-border-color-primary">
                <a href="oferta/view?id=<?= $teste['ofe_id']?>">
                    <img
                            src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').'/'.$teste['ofe_imagem']; ?>"
                            height="305px" width="338px"
                            onclick="visualizacao(<?= $teste['ofe_id']?>)"
                ></a>
                <div class=""><h4><?= $teste['ofe_titulo']; ?></h4></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p class="scroll" style="height: 150px"><?= $teste['ofe_desc'];?></p>
                    <!-- <button data-modal="full-success" class="btn btn-space btn-success md-trigger">Sucesso</button> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

-

```
<!--Textbox que recolher a descrição do item-->
<div id="div_ofe_desc">
    <label class="label-control">Descrição</label>
    <textarea name="ofe_desc" class="form-control" id="ofe_desc" rows="5" cols="30" required></textarea>
</div>
```

-

```
if (isset($_POST['ofe_titulo'])) {
        $conteudoDaImagem = Yii::$app->request->post('imagem');

        //define alguns atributos e recebe outros
        $model->ofe_emp_id      = Yii::$app->user->identity->usu_emp_id;
        $model->ofe_cliques     = 0;
        $model->ofe_visualizacao= 0;

        $model->ofe_sub_id      = $_POST['subcategoria'];
        $model->ofe_titulo      = $_POST['ofe_titulo'];
        $model->ofe_tipo_id     = $_POST['ofe_tipo_id'];
        $model->ofe_redir       = $_POST['ofe_redir'];

        if($_POST['ofe_valor_neutro'] == null || $_POST['ofe_valor_neutro'] == ''){
            $model->ofe_valor_neutro = 0;        
        }else{
            $model->ofe_valor_neutro= $_POST['ofe_valor_neutro'];
        }

        if($_POST['ofe_valor_desc'] == null || $_POST['ofe_valor_desc'] == ''){
            $model->ofe_valor_desc = 0;        
        }else{
            $model->ofe_valor_desc  = $_POST['ofe_valor_desc'];
        }

        if($_POST['ofe_valor_frete'] == null || $_POST['ofe_valor_frete'] == ''){
            $model->ofe_frete = 0;        
        }else{
            $model->ofe_frete       = $_POST['ofe_valor_frete'];
        }

        if($_POST['ofe_valor_atual'] == null || $_POST['ofe_valor_atual'] == ''){
            $model->ofe_valor_atual = 0;        
        }else{
            $model->ofe_valor_atual = $_POST['ofe_valor_atual'];
        }

        $model->ofe_desc        = $_POST['ofe_desc'];
        $model->ofe_regra       = $_POST['ofe_regra'];
        $model->ofe_status      = $_POST['Oferta']['ofe_status'];
        $model->save();

        //realiza upload da imagem da oferta e mostra a tela View
        if($model->uploadImagem()){
            $model->save();
            $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ofe_id]);
        }else{
            pe("erro");
        }


    }
```

Como esta aparecendo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tu chegou a acessar o banco de dados para ver o que está sendo salvo? O mais provável é que teu backend esteja removendo o HTML antes de salvar. Consegue colocar o teu código backend onde tu faz a escrita no banco? Talvez seja característica do teu framework fazer isso

Comment: toda a parte de formulário, seja o Forms ou Post, estão em HTML e PHP básicos, mas posso mostrar sim. só um momento

Comment: Já experimentou definir a propriedade CSS [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) com o valor `pre` ou `pre-wrap`? Assim o HTML vai renderizar quebras de linha ao invés de ignorar.

Comment: Já tentou salvar a linha como `outerHTML`? Ele mostra o HTML, dê uma olhada se ajuda.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, com um Pre-wrap, muito obrigado pela ajuda!.